# Serializer results in KeyError after correct data input and save

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm creating an API endpoint that works and saves data through its API.  It works, but my concern is that it throws a KeyError as shown below.  I'm not sure if this is an issue with my code.  Your help is very much appreciated.

Data:

```
data = {'title': u'abc', 'career_level': 1}
```

Serializer:

```
class JobPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    career_level = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, queryset=CareerLevel.objects.all(), required=False)
    title = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, max_length=240, required=False)
```

Model:

```
class JobPost(models.Model):
    career_level = models.ForeignKey(CareerLevel, related_name='jobpost_career', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

Error Message:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/posts/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/panbecopy/src/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/panbecopy/src/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/panbecopy/src/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/panbecopy/src/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 87, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/panbecopy/src/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/panbecopy/src/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/panbecopy/src/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 22, in create
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/panbecopy/src/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 503, in data
    ret = super(Serializer, self).data
  File "/home/ubuntu/panbecopy/src/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 241, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/panbecopy/src/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 463, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "/home/ubuntu/panbecopy/src/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 157, in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/panbecopy/src/penv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 78, in get_attribute
    instance = instance[attr]
KeyError: u'career_level'
```

Comment: Can you post the models.py as well?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the REST framework, but a KeyError usually means that you are trying to reference a key in a dictionary that doesn't exist.

Comment: That's how I understand KeyError as well, but I can't seem to locate where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Your serializer definition makes no sense.

```
JobPostSerializer(data={'title': u'abc', 'career_level': 1}):
```

It should instead be:

```
class JobPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

That line of yours is more similar to when you want to instantiate the serializer. Something like when you want to check if the input was valid, for example.

```
job_serializer = JobPostSerializer(data={'title': u'abc', 'career_level': 1})
job_serializer.is_valid()
```

Comment: Hey It's my bad but my serializers.py actually looks like what you've outlined here. I've printed out the instantiated serializers and pasted it here. (just edited it) Also checked `job_serializer.is_valid()` in my shell and it returns True...

Comment: Hm, that's odd then. Which version of DRF are you using? If you're using the latest (3), I'm not sure if it's supposed to work with Python 2.7.

Comment: I'm using Django==1.9
djangorestframework==3.3.3
and python 2.7